# No JTA platform available

Tags: api, rest, hibernate, jpa, spring-data

Parece que el error es de mapeo al realizar peticiones de una API Rest con Spring JPA [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El controller es el siguiente:

```
@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:5080")
@RestController
/* Establecer URL de inicio para realizar peticiones */
@RequestMapping("/api")
public class UserController {
    @Autowired
    UserServiceImpl userServiceImpl;

    // Read
    @GetMapping("/user")
    public List<User> getAllUser() {
        return userServiceImpl.getAllUser();

    }

    // Read for id
    @GetMapping("/user/{user_id}")
    public ResponseEntity<User> getPokemonForId(@PathVariable int user_id) {
        User userForId = userServiceImpl.getUserForId(user_id);
        return ResponseEntity.ok(userForId);

    }

    // Create
    @PostMapping("/save/user")
    public ResponseEntity<User> saveUser(@RequestBody User user) {
        User newUser = userServiceImpl.saveUser(user);
        return new ResponseEntity<>(newUser, HttpStatus.CREATED);
    }

    // Update
    @PutMapping("update/user/{user_id}")
    public ResponseEntity<User> updateUser(@PathVariable int user_id, @RequestBody User user) {
        User userForId = userServiceImpl.getUserForId(user_id);
        userForId.setUser_nick(user.getUser_nick());
        userForId.setUser_password(user.getUser_password());
        userForId.setUser_email(user.getUser_email());
        userForId.setUser_avatar(user.getUser_avatar());
        /* Create a new updated user */
        User userUpdate = userServiceImpl.saveUser(userForId);
        return new ResponseEntity<>(userUpdate, HttpStatus.OK);

    }

    // Delete
    @DeleteMapping("delete/user/{user_id}")
    public ResponseEntity<HashMap<String, Boolean>> deleteUserForId(@PathVariable int user_id) {
        this.userServiceImpl.deleteUserforId(user_id);
        HashMap<String, Boolean> DeletePokemonState = new HashMap<>();
        DeletePokemonState.put("Deleted", true);
        return ResponseEntity.ok(DeletePokemonState);
    }

}
```

El servidor Tomcat inicia el servicio correctamente con el puerto sin embargo me da el error del inicio.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si alguien sabe el porque puede ser, yo pienso que es de mappeo porque no da ningún error sin embargo no tengo ni idea de porqué no me funciona y me da este error.
También he probado realizar las peticiones con postman y me sigue dando error:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Diría que springboot no encuentra tu controller entero, has configurado correctamente springboot para que busque en los paquetes donde tienes el controller?

Comment: en tu log viene el problema y lo que debes hacer, te recomiendo ponerlo como texto para que te lo podamos traducir

Answer (score 0):

Ya esta solucionado el problema, no tenia los directorios controller,model,repository y service dentro del paquete donde esta la clase principal del proyecto  por lo que no los leía bien al hacer esto ya me ha funcionado correctamente.

Comment: Tal y como está redactada, tu respuesta no es clara. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir detalles adicionales que ayuden a los demás a entender cómo esto responde a la pregunta formulada. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).